# Strictly-Typed-Languages: “New”-Design Pattern?

Tags: type-systems

I am writing extensively in a typed language in the last couple of months and wondering what a proper pattern for this behaviour is:

- When I create a new database entry (whatever this is) I am receiving parameters via an API
- Once the entry is created, it also has an id attached to it

So for each item, I have a type `NewItem` **without** the id, and `Item` **with** the id. I do this so the compiler is not upset by checking against the parameters in the request, and then once the item is created, I have to have an item type with the id.

Is this common practice to always have to two types for the same item?

Comment: Does your language support something like [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) / [Maybe](https://wiki.haskell.org/Maybe) types?

Comment: It does! So then if I require an id in the code, instead of relying on the type, I need an if to confirm it includes an id.

Comment: The important question here is whether the `NewItem` and `Item` types are being used in the same manner.  That is, can a `NewItem` be a substitute for an Item or does it need to 'graduate' to an `Item` first?

Comment: @ohboy21 [isPresent()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) is [not the recommended use of optional](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/java8-optional.html). The point is to avoid the need for distracting checks.

Comment: @candied_orange Can you point me to a pattern?

Comment: @JimmyJames By creation, I have a NewItem before the db entry, and an Item once I retrieve it and send it back to the client.

Comment: @ohboy21 lambdas come to mind. One that returns the known existing id. One that creates the database entry and returns the new id. Now the types are the same and the behavior is different. If not lambdas the strategy pattern comes to mind. Either way you have a place in your code that doesn't care if it exists yet or not.

Comment: I don't think you answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this common practice to always have to two types for the same item?

No, I don't think this is common practice - not because it would be a bad idea in general, but simply for economics. In any real-world system I remember, there was only one type used for this, for "new" entries as well as for persistent entries, both with an ID or primary key attribute. As long as the ID is not known, it is set to a special value (like zero or NULL or -1 or `undef`), and when the record is created, the entry gets its final ID.

Maintaining two almost identical types, however, doubles the maintenance effort, and introduces a risk of changing one type whilst forgetting about the other.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but some food for thought.

I've been trying to do something similar with Rust which is strongly typed (coming from a Smalltalk background, a pretty big change.) What I've come up with (should work in any language with parameterized types):

```rust
struct Id<T> {
    primitive_id: u64,       // or whatever primitive type is suitable in your DB
    phantom: PhantomData<T>, // not a true member, but a holder for the type
                             // so the type system can do its work
}

struct Persistent<T> {
    id: Id<T>,
    value: T,
}
```

By implementing `Deref` and/or `DerefMut` traits, you can treat `Persistent<Item>` almost like you can treat `Item`. I've also defined a `Repository<T>` trait approximately so:

```rust
trait Repository<T> { // in reality, async trait because the database framework is async
    fn insert(&mut self, item: T) -> Persistent<T>;
    fn get(&self, id: Id<T>) -> Option<Persistent<T>>;
}
```

One nice thing is that you can define foreign key fields in database structs as `Id<ReferencedType>` which makes dealing with them type-safe. If your database implements both `Repository<TypeA>` and `Repository<TypeB>` you could just use `db.get(id)` where `id` is an `Id<TypeA>` to retrieve a `Persistent<TypeA>` and similar for `TypeB`.

I found that pretty slick (even though I curse the rigid typesystem at least twice per hour).

However, this only solves the issue for creating and persisting data within the service - you may have to define separate types for a RESTful API since there you probably don't want to deal with `Id<>` values but with other kinds of data that identify references.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would say not to go crazy overthinking it. A lot of software problems come from an obsession with never repeating any code, ever, so sometimes the easiest thing is to just have a little duplicated code (such as 2 similar entities which cannot be easily associated with something like a parent class). Having said that, I've personally thought about the problem you describe quite a bit, and lately, here's how I'll structure my classes where there's a version with an ID once its persisted, but without an ID beforehand.

```
public abstract class WidgetBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}

// This is only used by the 'CreateWidget' code pathway.
public class UnsavedWidgetDetails : WidgetBase
{
    public string NewWidgetSpecialInstructions { get; set; } // maybe this is logged, but not part of the real Widget model.
}

// Here's the 'real' Widget that is used throughout the app after creation
public class Widget : WidgetBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

This approach works pretty well for me. You can add Constructors as needed. However it runs into problems because C#/Java do not allow for multiple inheritance or mixins yet, so sometimes I just have to repeat same-named properties across these classes instead of having them inherit from an abstract base. And when that happens, its really not a huge problem.